# chat box post enter value which is not supposed to?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using the below code,

In this code, when i only press enter key the form submit, i want to check whether there is any thing written and it does not post empty string it accept enter which is not supposed to it should check any thing other than enter.

So please suggest me how should i check whether it returns some values or just enter, like in gtalk or in fb chat.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.commentarea').keyup(function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) 
  {
      var content = this.value;
      var caret = getCaret(this);
      this.value = content.substring(0, caret) + "\n" + content.substring(carent, content.length - 1);
      event.stopPropagation();
  } else if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $('form').submit();
  }
});

function getCaret(el) {
  if (el.selectionStart) 
  {
      return el.selectionStart;
  } else if (document.selection) 
  {
      el.focus();
      var r = document.selection.createRange();
      if (r == null) 
      {
          return 0;
      }

      var re = el.createTextRange(),
      rc = re.duplicate();
      re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
      rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);

      return rc.text.length;
  }
  return 0;
}
});
</script>
<?php echo $_POST['commentarea']?> 
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea name="commentarea" class="commentarea"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: `else if (event.keyCode == 13) { $('form').submit(); }` Looks suspicious.

Comment: the code is working fine the only thing i want to know why it didnt take the value of return key since it is just null value